# How to add R2 for each facet of ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, ggpubr, ggpmisc

Is there a way to first change the facet label from `1:3` to something like `c(good, bad, ugly)`. Also, i would like to add `R2` value to each of the facet. Below is my code- i tried a few things but didn't succeed.

```
DF = data.frame(SUB = rep(1:3, each = 100), Ob = runif(300, 50,100), S1 = runif(300, 75,95), S2 = runif(300, 40,90),
                S3 = runif(300, 35,80),S4 = runif(300, 55,100))
FakeData = gather(DF, key = "Variable", value = "Value", -c(SUB,Ob))

ggplot(FakeData, aes(x = Ob, y = Value))+
  geom_point()+ geom_smooth(method="lm") + facet_grid(Variable ~ SUB,  scales = "free_y")+
  theme_bw()
```

Here is the figure that i am getting using above code.
[image]
I tried below code to change the facet_label but it didn't work

```
ggplot(FakeData, SUB = factor(SUB, levels = c("Good", "Bad","Ugly")), aes(x = Ob, y = Value))+
  geom_point()+ geom_smooth(method="lm") + facet_grid(Variable ~ SUB,  scales = "free_y")+
  theme_bw()
```

I do not have any idea how to add `R2` to the `facets`. Is there any efficient way of computing and `R2` to the `facets`?

Comment: To change SUB levels into "good", "bad" and "ugly", you can use either `fct_recode()` or `case_when()`, e.g.: `DF %>% mutate(SUB = fct_recode(as.character(SUB), good = "1", bad = "2", ugly = "3"))"` or `DF %>% mutate(SUB = case_when(SUB == 1 ~ "good", SUB == 2 ~ "bad", SUB == 3 ~ "ugly"))`

Comment: To get R2, you will probably need to iterate linear models over the subsets of your data that you want the R2 for. The most straightforward & painless way to do that is to use nested dataframes (see: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html). Try reading the link and figuring out a way to do it for yourself - learning how to iterate my workflow properly was an invaluable skill for me. If you get stuck, comment here or create a new post.

Comment: To change `SUB` use `labels` rather than `levels` like this `mutate(SUB = factor(SUB, labels = c("Good", "Bad", "Ugly")))`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `ggpubr::stat_cor()` to easily add correlation coefficients to your plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

FakeData %>%
  mutate(SUB = factor(SUB, labels = c("good", "bad", "ugly"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Ob, y = Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  facet_grid(Variable ~ SUB,  scales = "free_y") +
  theme_bw() +
  stat_cor(aes(label = after_stat(rr.label)), color = "red", geom = "label")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there away to have both ‘R^2’ and ‘p-value’ on the figure?

Comment: Use `stat_cor(aes(label = paste(..rr.label.., ..p.label.., sep = "~")), color = "red", geom = "label")`

Comment: Wow, this worked like a charm. Late at night, in crunch mode, with no hiccups. Almost too good to be true!

Comment: In ggplot2 3.4.0 the preferred syntax was changed and is now `aes(label = after_stat(rr.label))` .

Comment: @G.Grothendieck - thank you Gabor - have updated.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use functions from other packages and only want to use `ggplot2`, you will need to compute the `R2` for each `SUB` and `Variable` combination, and then add to your plot with `geom_text` or `geom_label`. Here is one way to do it.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

DF = data.frame(SUB = rep(1:3, each = 100), Ob = runif(300, 50,100), S1 = runif(300, 75,95), S2 = runif(300, 40,90),
                S3 = runif(300, 35,80),S4 = runif(300, 55,100))
FakeData = gather(DF, key = "Variable", value = "Value", -c(SUB,Ob))

FakeData_lm <- FakeData %>%
  group_by(SUB, Variable) %>%
  nest() %>%
  # Fit linear model
  mutate(Mod = map(data, ~lm(Value ~ Ob, data = .x))) %>%
  # Get the R2
  mutate(R2 = map_dbl(Mod, ~round(summary(.x)$r.squared, 3))) 

ggplot(FakeData, aes(x = Ob, y = Value))+
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_smooth(method="lm") + 
  # Add label
  geom_label(data = FakeData_lm, 
             aes(x = Inf, y = Inf, 
                 label = paste("R2 = ", R2, sep = " ")),
             hjust = 1, vjust = 1) +
  facet_grid(Variable ~ SUB,  scales = "free_y") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following answer makes use of package 'ggpmisc' (version >= 0.5.0 for the second example). In addition, I simply used a call to `factor()` within `aes()` to set the labels.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc)

DF = data.frame(SUB = rep(1:3, each = 100), Ob = runif(300, 50,100), S1 = runif(300, 75,95), S2 = runif(300, 40,90),
                S3 = runif(300, 35,80),S4 = runif(300, 55,100))
FakeData = gather(DF, key = "Variable", value = "Value", -c(SUB,Ob))

# As asked in the question
# Ensuring that the R^2 label does not overlap the observations
ggplot(FakeData, aes(x = Ob, y = Value)) +
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
  stat_poly_eq() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.1, 0.33))) +
  facet_grid(Variable ~ factor(SUB, 
                               levels = 1:3,
                               labels = c("good", "bad", "ugly")), 
             scales = "free_y") +
  theme_bw()

# As asked in a comment, adding P-value
ggplot(FakeData, aes(x = Ob, y = Value))+
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
  stat_poly_eq(mapping = use_label(c("R2", "P")), p.digits = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.1, 0.33))) +
  facet_grid(Variable ~ factor(SUB, 
                               levels = 1:3,
                               labels = c("good", "bad", "ugly")),
             scales = "free_y")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

And the plot from the second example adding *P* to the label.

*Note:* With older versions of 'ggpmisc' which lack function `use_label()` the mapping can be written as `aes(label = paste(after_stat(rr.label), after_stat(p.label), sep = "*\", \"*")` in the same way as when using 'ggpubr'.

[image]

Package 'ggpubr' includes code copied from 'ggpmisc' without acknowledgenment, which explains why some statistics are so similar between the two packages. 'ggpmisc' is more narrowly focused but the statistics in it have been much improved after they were taken into 'ggpubr'. 'ggpmisc' is actively maintained while maintenance of 'ggpubr' seems currently stalled.